# Troubles after renaming table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I've changed my table name in rails, and after that I receive this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "old_table_name" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"old_table_name"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"old_table_name"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

What should I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your model, controllers, associations, etc. are corrected as well. The error indicates that there's a part of your Rails app that is still using the old name.

This error looks like it's from the Rails log. If you look a few lines before the `PG::Error` it should indicate the portion of the code that makes this reference, and should therefore tell you where the correction needs to be made.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing more in log file, what is more I think, that I've corrected all places.

Comment: You may *think* you've corrected all places... but you plainly *haven't* :-)  Have you searched your whole code base for the old table name? Does it get stored in the DB itself anywhere (as part of STI or polymorphic type names, maybe)? Is it "built" by string concatenation (which would hide from global searches)?. Upshot: stick a breakpoint on that line, and then inspect all the variables and code around it to see where the error is.

Comment: Yes, I've search whole application folder in sublime. I am new in rails, so it was a very simple model.

Comment: The breakpoint idea is a good one. Try using debugging to see if you can get to the center of the problem. Is the code for your project open source? It is accessible somewhere that I can inspect (e.g. github)?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error explicitly refers to a `relation`, I am guessing somewhere you still have a

```
has_many :old_names
```

or

```
 belongs_to :old_name
```

Also: did you change any foreign-keys to match the new name? E.g. `new_table_name_id` instead of `old_table_name_id` ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not have any relations between tables.

Comment: How did you change the table-name? Did you change the class name as well?

Comment: I' ve used changed method. I' decided to return to state before renaming. In the future probably I would like to try rename tables in my project again, but now I' d like to code some logic in my application.